# head() function appends all results to the end

Tags: r, sorting, dataset

I am trying to learn R, but running into some (for me) unexpected behaviour. I have a data set of 4000 imdb movies. And want to get the top 5 movies sorted by their ratings, and their budget. I bind this data to `datsort` using:

```
datsort <- arrange(dat, desc(imdb_score), budget)
```

then get the first 5 results sorted by title using
`head(datsort$movie_title,n=5)`
 which mostly returns what I expected.

The total data returned I get is

```
[1] Towering Inferno             
[2] The Shawshank Redemption     
[3] The Godfather                
[4] Kickboxer: Vengeance         
[5] Dekalog                      
3928 Levels: #Horror  [Rec] 2  [Rec]  ... Zulu
```

However appended to the list of top 5 movies is:

```
3928 Levels: #Horror  [Rec] 2  [Rec]  ... Zulu
```

Which seems totally unrelated, as it is just the complete list of movies, sorted alphabetically

What I expected is just

```
[1] Towering Inferno             
[2] The Shawshank Redemption     
[3] The Godfather                
[4] Kickboxer: Vengeance         
[5] Dekalog
```

from reading documentation and examples I've never seen the total list appended. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read about `?factor` and check out the examples.

Comment: `factor(c("b", "a"))`

Comment: use option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading in your data.

Comment: How did you read in the data? if it was `read.csv` there's a parameter `stringsAsFactors`. In modern times — for most workflows — this should always be forced `FALSE`. It defaults to `TRUE`. Also, you used `arrange` so why not use `top_n` or `slice`? https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ may not be the best "intro R" book but it has a methodical approach that may help you with your R journey.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Both of your methods worked. Is there a situation in which one is better than the other?

@hrbrmstr thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: https://simplystatistics.org/2015/07/24/stringsasfactors-an-unauthorized-biography/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have alluded to, your `movie_title` column is stored as a factor. A quick fix is to run the following, which converts your column to a character, before your `head`-call. In turn, the printing method will not show all the levels.

```
 datsort$movie_title <- as.character(datsort$movie_title)

 head(datsort$movie_title,n=5)
 #[1] Towering Inferno             
 #[2] The Shawshank Redemption     
 #[3] The Godfather                
 #[4] Kickboxer: Vengeance         
 #[5] Dekalog
```

Better yet, use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you read in your data (or create your data.frame) as @phiver suggest in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for bundling it as an answer. Will accept this for future reference as i cannot accept comments